# Flutter retrieval of data broken when using session?

Tags: php, flutter

This is how i view the result from php.

> 

```
final String uri =
'My PHP FILE';
Future<List<Dbjobs>> dbgetdbusers() async {
var response = await http.get(uri);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
List<Dbjobs> dbusers = items.map<Dbjobs>((json) {
return Dbjobs.fromJson(json);
}).toList();
print(dbusers);
return dbusers;
} else {
throw Exception('Failed to load data.');
}
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder<List<Dbjobs>>(
future: dbgetdbusers(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (!snapshot.hasData)
return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
return ListView(
children: snapshot.data
.map((data) => Column(
children: <Widget>[
GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => JobDetails()));
},
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[
Container(
color: Colors.grey,
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[
Align(
alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
child: Text(
data.dateCreated,
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
),
),
```

My Login Php

> 

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'testConz.php';
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password =md5($_POST['Password']);   
$Consult = $connect -> query("SELECT * FROM tuser_ppim WHERE LoginName = '$username' and Password = '$password' ");
$Result = array();
while ($extractData=$Consult->fetch_assoc()) {
$Result[] = $extractData;
}
$ID = $Result['0']['ID'];
$_SESSION['$Consult'] = $Result;
echo json_encode($Result); 
?>
>
```

This php file works with flutter, there are results based on the query.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'testConz.php';  
$Consult1=$connect->query("
SELECT * FROM tjob WHERE AssignedTo = '6';
");
$Outcome1 = array();
while ($extractData=$Consult1->fetch_assoc()) {
$Outcome1[] = $extractData;
}
echo json_encode($Outcome1);
?>
>
```

This one makes my screen loads with no result. any ideas?

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'testConz.php';
$userDetails = $_SESSION['$Consult'];
$SesID = $userDetails['0']['ID']; 
$Consult1=$connect->query("
SELECT * FROM tjob WHERE AssignedTo = ".$SesID.";
    ");
$Outcome1 = array();
while ($extractData=$Consult1->fetch_assoc()) {
$Outcome1[] = $extractData;
}
echo json_encode($Outcome1);
echo json_encode($userDetails);
?>
>
```

BTW both produces the number for AssignedTo is equal 6
AND
Both produces the same result when in browser. but when it is in flutter screen the other one has no result.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you passing a session id anywhere?

Comment: yeah, i pass it to a query. but what happens is when i run the php file in the browser it works, but when i add the file to flutter mobile it just loads

Comment: You are echoing two separate `json_encode` results there - which together, coming one after the other, will _not_ be valid JSON any more. So if your flutter app expects valid JSON, it might simply fail when it tries to parse the response.

Comment: i see, ill try removing one then, im kinda new to queries and still playing with dbeaver to experiment on db queries. thank you for the insight.